# Existing users looking deleted here on meta?

Tags: support, migration, users

I just clicked through to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254433/11410) and though *"Wow! Norman Ramsey dropped his account, what happened?!"*

Digging in a bit, I discovered that he is (at least virtually) [alive and well](https://stackexchange.com/users/18251/norman-ramsey?tab=accounts).

So what happened, is this some weirdness because of the migration?

(Sorry if this is a dupe, couldn't find anything with the search terms that came to mind)

Comment: Interesting, good find. Not sure if this is a duplicate question, but I'd like to know the answer as well.

Comment: He hasn't come to MSO yet. If you look at his SO profile, there is no sign of a Meta user yet. http://stackoverflow.com/users/41661/norman-ramsey

Answer (score 6):

Only users that have actually visited Meta.SO have an account here.

For posts migrated from Meta.SE, that means that even Stack Overflow regulars may *look* deleted here. Until Norman Ramsey visits Meta.SO, he doesn't have an account *yet*.

Don't worry, noone actually deleted Meta.SO accounts.

Comment: I demand to know who is this noone guy and how many accounts he deleted! ;)

Comment: I direct you to the office of General Protection Fault for further enquiries. Press Any Key to continue.

Comment: I pressed ALT+F4 to continue and now I can't see the page anymore!

Comment: The correct key combination is `CTRL-ALT-DELETE`.