# What should I flag homework/tell me what this does questions?

Tags: discussion, flags

I know this question has been asked before [Please clarify the policy on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/please-clarify-the-policy-on-homework-questions) and I've looked through the answers, but when I came across this question

[image]

I wasn't sure what to flag it. The meta answer says vote to close, but when I look at the options under voting to close this didn't really fit into any of them.

There's no "vote to close because the user has not put any work into answering his own question."

What category would this have fit under?

Comment: Post is already gone.

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."_ Seems adequate for _"What does this code do?"_ questions.

Comment: @Deduplicator I included that link in my question...

Comment: And the most upvoted answer there also answers this question.

Comment: You could also go for the faq: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254433/should-i-send-students-to-stack-overflow

Comment: "Too broad" and "Unclear" are both good. As there's not a specific question, nor any other way to gauge where to start the explanation.

Comment: @Deduplicator but it's not too broad or unclear. The user wants to know what the code will print and provides the code itself. There's only one answer to the code, and that isn't an opinion. Also the question seems to fit the "Questions seeking debugging help" option. The desired behavior is it prints something, they want to know what it prints, and they provide the code for it. The problem with the question is that it's just extremely low effort and lazy, showing no work on the askers part. There's not a flag for that

Comment: @MartijnPieters could you perhaps explain this to me. The question fits under none of the "close this question" flags as I specified above. What should it be flagged.

Comment: If it doesn't fit under anything to flag it as, why are you trying to flag it?

Comment: @Makoto I'm just confused that a question that gets downvoted to -7 and then deleted by the user himself doesn't have an appropriate flag category.

Comment: I wish there was a close option that was "This user has put not effort into finding an answer."

Comment: @AR7: if it doesn't fit under a close reason, *it is not off topic*. Homework and low research effort are not reasons to close a post. You just downvote it for lack of research.

Comment: @AR7: *Generally speaking* most 'explain this code to me' questions are too broad, because the OP almost always did not specify what exactly about the code they did not understand. You could then potentially get an endless stream of follow-up questions as you try to determine exactly what they didn't understand about the code, including how computers work.

Comment: @AR7:  In that scenario, there's no action required.  The user's already removed the content, and the community has expressed its opinion on it.  No flags required.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that makes sense. My last question would be: why are downvoting and flagging sometimes mutually exclusive? If it deserves a downvote, why shouldn't it be flagged as well.

Comment: @AR7: some questions are very well researched and written and interesting, but off topic. Some questions are on topic, but terrible quality. Quality and on-topicness are two different aspects, don't confuse the two.

Comment: @MartijnPieters okay thank you very much! I appreciate that you answered my questions instead of just redirecting me to another answer or FAQ.