# How do I flag lazy homework questions?

Tags: support, homework

There's already a question on this topic here: [What should I flag homework/tell me what this does questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298117/what-should-i-flag-homework-tell-me-what-this-does-questions). Unfortunately it doesn't have an answer.

There's another question about how to ask *good* homework questions: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), which is great, but this is about *lazy* homework questions, specifically how to flag them.

Then there's another question here: [Please clarify the policy on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255477/please-clarify-the-policy-on-homework-questions). The answer to that question just adds to the confusion.

**How do I flag obvious lazy homework questions?**

The reason I'm asking this is because I want to vote to close this question: [Assembly language multiplies two single precision floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424726/assembly-language-multiplies-two-single-precision-floating-point-numbers).

It's clearly not a good question, at a minimum because it doesn't [include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

I had a look at the "off topic" flag options, but none of them fit:

[image]

The question is not a duplicate (I don't think), it's on-topic, it doesn't need more clarity (what it's asking is clear, as is the case for all homework questions), I suppose it might need more focus (kinda?), and it's not opinion-based. It's still a terrible question though.

How do I flag it? I seem to recall there used to be a homework flag..

**EDIT:** There's some close votes piling up from other answers that refer to "too broad" as the correct flag. **Too Broad** is not an actual option you can click, so I don't see how those links are a useful replacement for this question/answer.

Comment: The "*Answering and moderating homework questions*" section answers your question. *"As with homework questions, other questions along the lines of "plz send teh codez" may be closed as "too broad""* Now the close is reason is changed to "Needs more foucs"

Comment: It's changed to *"Needs more focus"* (This is very vague compared to *Too Broad* IMO)

Comment: So what about the vast subset of lazy "plz send teh codez" questions that address _a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer_, or is the assumption that there is no such thing?

Comment: I mean, isn't it in the nature of homework questions that they are specific enough to identify an adequate answer? How else does the teacher grade them?

Comment: You don't flag them. They are on topic.

Comment: @ayhan so we're cool with that question then?

Comment: If none of the close reasons apply to that question then yes.

Comment: @ayhan ok but that directly contradicts the help center, which says that homework questions _must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem_.

Comment: I think @adiga's response answers my question.

Comment: @gnat I think it contains the right information, but it's not helpful as a dupe since "Too broad" doesn't exist (anymore), so it won't actually help anyone looking for the answer. I've tried to answer the question myself for the next person.

Comment: well, I've seen complaints about new wording of "too broad" reason ([example here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391950/839601)) and I dislike this change myself. However, I keep using "more focus" the same way as before and see others doing that so for practical purposes it seems to be a working substitute. Change feels a bit painful but at least not as bad as [removal of Lacks Minimal Understanding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/257868/839601)

Comment: I find that the easiest way to handle homework questions in general is to just ignore that they're homework questions and treat them exactly the same as I would any other question of the same quality. We don't need a "homework flag" because bad homework questions can already be dealt with by another flag ("needs focus" or "needs details" typically) and good homework questions are perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suppose with these questions, it is irrelevant that it is homework. It is classified as a "Lazy" or "Send the codez" question, and should be treated as such.

I would like to point out the hover text on the downvote button:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

For the type of questions you point out, all three of these are true. So the obvious answer (for me at least) should be:

### Downvote the question

**This should be your first action on any of these questions**. It's a slap on the nose for people being lazy and having others do their job/homework for them. However, this creates another issue. Often people don't understand why they are being downvoted, and see this community as rude or confusing.

**Now this is both a good and a bad thing.**

It is good because it will weed out "Spam" or "Lazy" posters as the ones mentioned here. If these questions are answered, these people will flock to the site by droves, which will depreciate the value of the site significantly. Chasing them off with a (downvote) stick seems appropriate in this case.

It is bad because it will also hurt genuine people trying to get answers who don't know how the site works. They will be chased off with the same stick and probably not come back even though they might be users that after some time of improvement, we'd happily have on our site.

The way I get around this is to leave a comment. Often with a short explanation or a link to [why I downvoted](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). (This link gives a much better explanation as to what the reader has done wrong than any comment ever could.) The lazy people won't read and be chased off, the genuine people will read this and understand/improve their behaviour.

### As for the flagging

It is important questions like these are closed to prevent rep-farming, but the flag you raise at this point is more or less irrelevant. Once a question begins to accumulate downvotes, it sends a clear message to anyone that this question does not belong here.

The most appropriate flag in most cases would be **"Needs more focus"** as most of these are one line questions with a general problem, not enough focus to write the exact code required to solve the problem.

Another acceptable flag would be **"Needs details or clarity"** as often details about the surroundings of the questions are needed, and it is unclear what kind of answer is expected for the question.

Answer (score 2):

The ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions-) question does actually contain the answer to this question, albeit burried pretty deep and referring to old terminology that would have prevented me from recognising it as an answer. Here it is sanitised:

> As with homework questions, other questions along the lines of "plz
>   send teh codez" may be closed as "**Needs more focus**". Use your best judgment.
>   Remember: students are new programmers and often do not yet understand
>   what is expected of them on the site. We should politely and patiently
>   help them gain that understanding.

I've changed "too broad" to "Needs more focus" which is apparently the new name for it. I can only assume the same rules still apply to that new option.