# For what reason should this question be closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I think all would agree that it is correct that this question:

[Need the explain for correct choices. "Kotlin"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73458337/need-the-explain-for-correct-choices-kotlin)

was closed.

However I struggle to find the reason for it in the list.

My options:

- Duplicate: not a duplicate
- A community-specific reason: see below
- Needs details or clarity: the question is clear
- Needs more focus: it's a single specific question
- Opinion-based: no this question definitely has an answer

Community-specific reasons:

- Not about programming or software development: it is about programming
- Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more: nope
- Needs debugging details: not applicable
- Not reproducible or was caused by a typo: not applicable
- This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: It also doesn't belong on other sites of stack exchange
- Other: I guess it must be this

So, what exactly should be the reason? Right now, it is closed for the "not about programming", but I fail to find a match for this specific case in the [guide lines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Maybe the right choice was be to just pick "Other". But what should be the explanation there. "This just doesn't belong here"?. "It is very low quality"?. Or what?

And the thing is, in my opinon, it actually happens quite often that I feel this is the reason that a question needs to be closed. Maybe another close reason needs to be added for it. Or maybe an addition to the guide lines as for why the "not about progamming" reason might be applicable here. What's your take on this?

Comment: There is no strict rule against homework dumps. It's a low quality zero effort question at first glance. That is something you downvote.

Comment: Believe it or not, the question is **not** clear because the author doesn't explain his issues or where they are stuck.  So the close reason is "Needs details or clarity".  It's obviously just a copy and paste from a homework assignment.  But in the end, for questions like this, the reason is less of an issue than just closing it

Comment: Two of the three users selected the custom close reason "I’m voting to close this question because it seems like the user is doing an online test and is after the answers.", which is ...not really a valid close reason.  (the third user picked "Needs more focus")

Comment: @psubsee2003 hmm.. I guess I see your point. While the question that he needs to answer is clear, it's not clear why he struggles with it. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm personally of the opinion that simply copy-pasting multiple choice questions, with no explanation of what you'd like to know other than the correct answer, is not really a suitable Stack Overflow question.  That said, I'm not sure what close reason maps best to it.  I lean toward "Needs details or clarity", as it's unclear what they're asking other than just the letter of the correct choice(s).

Comment: @Ivo that's exactly the idea

Comment: What if the custom reason was worded _"... because Stack Overflow is not a service meant to just dump your test's multiple-choice questions into."_? The question is blatantly off-topic, and as long as the gist of the reason is clear enough... Just get it closed.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, that'd be better than this. Even better would be something like "while specific questions about a test question may be on-topic, simply pasting a multiple choice question and asking for the answer is not."

Comment: Related: [How do I flag lazy homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392334/7296893)

Comment: Part of the problem here is that the close voter immediately deleted the comment providing the reason after voting, so the asker (and everyone else who's not a moderator, since only moderators can see deleted comments) is deprived of an explanation.

Comment: The question has been deleted **after** this post was made. Isn't that now against the rules/guidelines?

Comment: @AdrianMole I think so, but AFAICT it was deleted within *minutes* of this Meta question being posted, and "This question is being discussed on Meta" notices don't always get posted instantly, I think it's safe to assume that whoever deleted it didn't actually know this Meta discussion existed, and it should be undeleted once they realise it does.

Comment: @F1Krazy Fair comment. But I was more concerned with it being undeleted than for any forfeit on the part of the delete voters.

Comment: Should I maybe delete this question? Since the referred question is gone, but also because it really is a duplicate

Comment: I think there's a discussion to be had here. The related question was answered with "close as needs more focus" which can be an incredibly frustrating close reason for a narrowly-defined multiple choice question, and imo is not the right answer to this meta post. With the current close reasons, it can be really hard for an author to deduce what they did wrong.

Comment: @RyanM ordinary close voters could see this comment as a custom reason in close dialog even after its removal. I guess that second close voter likely doubled on it because it made much better sense than not-about-programming. My (minority) vote went for [needs focus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601 "'What's a mouse?'"). I think you as a mod can see it. Hope one day such minority votes will be [displayed in question timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284886/165773 "respective feature request")

Comment: FWIW, I tend to use a comment like the following if I encounter a question which is a copy pasta of their (homework) assignment: *"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be asking for* homework help, *which should include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. You can find information on how to ask a well received question on your homework in the FAQ: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/2029983)"*

Comment: @Ivo no there is no need to delete this question, it is a really good and complete signpost. It is still a question about homework dumps in general, not just about the specific question you linked to.

Comment: @ErikA very much agree with you, but unfortunately the running consensus seems to be that quality is not needed when it comes to bookkeeping. Whatever close reason is good enough, just as long as it is closed as soon as possible. Because... reasons?

Comment: @Gimby Because we don't want those questions answered and give OP the idea they can keep doing it, to get their homework done.